# Hide Div with jQuery Once Back Button Clicked

Tags: jquery, css, html, back, visible

I'm working on a site which has a div out of sight until a link is clicked.

This all works fine until the back button is pressed, and the "new" div is still displayed.

How can I set it up so that when the back button is clicked, the homepage reverts to its original state?

See http://electrickiwi.co.uk/test/fatr/3 for the example. If you click on the "News" link, a new div appears with a menu and content area. Click on "Home" and the div disappears, taking you back to the original homepage. Try clicking "News" again and then clicking the back button. The menu background (div.left) disappears, but the actual menu still shows up.

I think this is because the menu is in a fixed position; which it needs to be; but I want it to be hidden again when the back button is pressed.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this code below inside your hashchange callback

```
jQuery("#content").fadeOut(1300)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm unsure where you're telling me to include this. Would you be able to provide an example in context for me? Thanks!

Comment: $(window).bind('hashchange', function(event) {
        var tgt = location.hash.replace(/^#\/?/,'');
        if(tgt=='home'){
     jQuery("#content").fadeOut(1300)
        }
        }); 
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

Comment: Thank you so much - you are a lifesaver! Added the code and all appears to be working as intended. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use `toggle()`

This can change the visibility based on an event you specify

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you be able to put this in context for me? Would I use this in conjunction with the .unload() feature? Would you mind telling me how to implement this with the #menu div that I am wanting to hide if the back button is pressed?